# Unable to RDP to Ubuntu 18.0.4 from Windows

Tags: remote-desktop

I have just created a VM from Azure for Ubuntu 18.0.4, and I am trying to VM to the machine and keep on getting this issue

[image]

I would be grateful if anyone could help me understand what the issue is and how to get around it.

When setting up the VM I connected via PuTTY and followed these steps.

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-establish-simple-remote-desktop-access-between-ubuntu-and-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I had found a link for dealing with remote desktop and azure/ubuntu.
I hope this can help you as well:
[Enable remote desktop on azure ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698698/enable-remote-desktop-on-azure-ubuntu?rq=1)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it's better to include essential parts here. Your answer becomes invalide if the source is modified or removed.

Comment: @Coditoergosum, greetings from Vancouver Island.  I agree with you and apologies for just the link. The linked post is a detailed, with screenshots,  on using xrdp and xfce.